# OSX / Mac with Kitematic / Docker : Tunnel / Port forwarding for access via external url

Tags: macos, docker, gulp, docker-compose, portforwarding

**What would be the recommended best practise when it comes to tunneling / port forwarding for external access to local development.**

Achieving this is not a problem itself. Could set it up manual. But i would like to ask the community for recommended solutions that can be automated from my build for smooth external access to website / webapp.

#### Development setup

**Machine**: Mac/OSX
**Virtual setup**: Kinematic ( *Kinematic cli -> Docker machine -> VirtualBox* )
**Automation**: Gulp for automating all code and reload workflow. Docker compose for server automation.

Do we have any good **Gulp solution**? that can achieve this without compromising my Docker server setup. Open up / tunnel access to local ip and in the best of worlds give me a temp url i can hand over to whoever i want to check something out.

Comment: Can browsersync achieve this without running it's own local server solution?

Comment: Best solution so far is ngrok.io.  Download from their site did not work but "$ brew install homebrew/binary/ngrok2" did.  This can be automated from Gulp, need to check for solution to rewrite local file paths on website so files will load correctly.